# Combinatorics : Generating function

Tags: combinatorics

I am working on the below generating function and confused on how to start:

Let $g(n)$  be the number of subsets of $[n]$ in which the difference between any two elements of the set is at least three. Find the generating function for $g(n).$

Comment: If you know the value of $g(1),g(2),\dots,g(n-1)$ how can you compute the value of $g(n)$?

Comment: Does $[n]$ means $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$?

Comment: Yes, that is [n]

Comment: I would suggest to start by calculating the first few values of the sequence and then look for the sequence terms in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_{n-3}$ be a subset of $[n-3]$ satisfying the condition. You know that $A_{n-3} \subset [n]$ and it satisfies the conditions you desire. Additionally, $A_{n-3} \cup \{n\} \subset [n]$.

For each $A_{n-5} \subset [n-5]$ satisfying the condition, $A_{n-5} \subset [n-3]$ and satisfies the condition, so you only need consider sets of the form $A_{n-5} \cup \{n-2\}$. Similarly for $A_{n-4} \cup \{n-1\}$.

This gives a recurrence relation:

$$g(n) = 2g(n-3)+g(n-4)+g(n-5)$$

(I have not fully thought this through, and you should verify that I did not miss any subsets).

Next, let $$f(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0}g(n)x^n$$

Then:

$$f(x)-2x^3f(x)-x^4f(x)-x^5f(x) = g(0)+g(1)x+g(2)x^2+(g(3)-2g(0))x^3+(g(4)-2g(1)-g(0))x^4+(g(5)-2g(2)-g(1)-g(0))x^5+\sum_{n\ge 6} (g(n)-2g(n-3)-g(n-4)-g(n-5))x^n$$

Since $g(n)=2g(n-3)+g(n-4)+g(n-5)$, every term with a power greater than 4 has a coefficient of zero.

So:

$$f(x) = \dfrac{g(0)+g(1)x+g(2)x^2+(g(3)-2g(0))x^3+(g(4)-2g(1)-g(0))x^4}{1-2x^3-x^4-x^5}$$

It is easy to see that $g(0)=1, g(1)=2, g(2)=3, g(3)=4, g(4)=6$. So, this gives the generating function:

$$f(x) = \dfrac{1+2x+3x^2+2x^3+x^4}{1-2x^3-x^4-x^5}$$

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Actually, there is a simpler recurrence relation: $g(n)=g(n-1)+g(n-3)$. This yields the generating function $h(x) = \dfrac{1+x+x^2}{1-x-x^3}$. Fortunately, $$\dfrac{1+2x+3x^2+2x^3+x^4}{1-2x^3-x^4-x^5} = \dfrac{1+x+x^2}{1-x-x^3}$$